# Tables side by side

Tags: php, twig

How can I put two arrays side by side using twig ?

This is my input

[image: my array]

---

```html
{% for key, item in CompareArray %}
    {% for x in item %}
        <tr>
            {% if key =='last' %}
                <td> last</td>
            {% endif %}
                                
            {% if key == 'primary' %}
                <td> primary</td>
            {% endif %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor  %}
{% endfor %}
```

The desired output

[image: the effect that i want to get]

```css
table,td{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 1px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> last.val1 </td>
    <td> last.val2 </td>
    <td> last.val3 </td>
    <td> #### </td>
    <td> primary.val1 </td>
    <td> primary.val2 </td>
    <td> primary.val3 </td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>   
    <td> ... </td>
    <td> ... </td>
  </tr>
<table>
```

Comment: Could you expand the dump of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the shared information I see a couple of possible solutions.

But first confirm if I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve.

You want to have table where the item information of the `last` group is displayed first with a separator column and then the item information of the `primary` group on the left? And as seen in the screen shot of the array the number of items in the group isn't even necessarily the same?

First think to consider would be should we create two different tables one for `primary` group and one for `last` and style them through `css` to look as if they're in they are side by side.

```
{% for groupKey, items in CompareArray %}
    <table>
      {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ groupKey }}.{{ item.prop1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ groupKey }}.{{ item.prop2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ groupKey }}.{{ item.prop3 }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endfor %}
```

Second solution would be a complicated use of `attribute` this means that both arrays have to have same keys. Here you'd iterate over the largest group and then add the corresponding value from the other group. I'm using some `macro`s to better separate the logic. The `block` named `myTemplate` is the code you'd insert where you wanted the data to be displayed.

```
{% block myTemplate %}
    {% if CompareArray.last|length > CompareArray.primary|length %}
        {{ _self.lastIsLonger(CompareArray.last, CompareArray.primary) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ _self.primaryIsLonger(CompareArray.last, CompareArray.primary) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}


{% macro lastIsLonger(lastGroup, primaryGroup) %}
    {% set primaryLenght = primaryGroup|length %}

    <table>
      {% for k,item in lastGroup %}
        <tr>
            {{ _self.buildElementData(item) }}
            <td> #### </td>
            {{ _self.buildElementData(loop.index <= primaryLenght ? attribute(primaryGroup, k) : {}) }}
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro primaryIsLonger(lastGroup, primaryGroup) %}
   {% set lastGroupLength = lastGroup|length %}
   
   <table>
     {% for k,item in primaryGroup %}
       <tr>
           {{ _self.buildElementData(loop.index <= lastGroupLength ? attribute(lastGroup, k) : {}) }}
           <td> #### </td>
           {{ _self.buildElementData(item) }}
       </tr>
     {% endfor %}
   </table>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro buildElementData(item) %}
    <td>{{ item.prop1 ?? '' }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.prop2 ?? '' }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.prop3 ?? '' }}</td>
{% endmacro %}
```

If I understand what you're doing I think a third solution I think would be best. That is that from the **PHP** side you matched which items you wanted to compare so the data you'd insert would look something like this:

```php
[
    [
        'last' => [
            'prop1' => '...',
            'prop2' => '...',
            'prop3' => '...',
        ],
        'primary' => [
            'prop1' => '...',
            'prop2' => '...',
            'prop3' => '...',
        ],
    ], [
        'last' => [
            'prop1' => '...',
            'prop2' => '...',
            'prop3' => '...',
        ],
        'primary' => [
            'prop1' => '...',
            'prop2' => '...',
            'prop3' => '...',
        ],
    ]
];
```

This way you're not relying on dirty tricks and do most of the logic where it belongs. The corresponding generation template generation is thus much more pleasing.

```
{% block myTemplate %}
    <table>
      {% for row in CompareArray %}
        <tr>

            {{ _self.buildElementData(row.last ?? {}) }}
            <td> #### </td>
            {{ _self.buildElementData(row.primary ?? {}) }}
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}

{% macro buildElementData(item) %}
    <td>{{ item.prop1 ?? '' }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.prop2 ?? '' }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.prop3 ?? '' }}</td>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Why overcomplicate things and not just iterate over the keys of the multidimensional array?

Comment: @DarkBee I don't know what you mean? You could do `foreach($array['first'] as $k => $value)`, and than access `$array['primary'][$key]` to get the corresponding item. But this is in PHP, in twig you can't access a dynamic/variable key in any other way than `attribute(array,key)` which is the solution 2. But again you don't really have the guaranty the keys are the same, and as you can see there is a different amount count of both items.

Comment: As from OP's screenshot, the keys aren't the same

Comment: @DarkBee I'm talking about the items in the `'last'`and `'primary'` array items. The OP to the best of my understanding wants to iterate them and display them side by side ie. `$array['last'][0]` next to `$array['primary'][0]`

Comment: Well OP is not replying, but I've made a simplified version of this - [demo](https://twigfiddle.com/adpwlf)

Comment: Well, I always accessed all elements always as `objectOrArray.keyOrProp` and was led to believe by reading some Twig issues on Gihub there was no way to access dynamic properties AND KEY, but I was wrong. I guess you can do `array[key]`where `key` is dynamic. Good to know. Thank you @DarkBee, I due think now that your solution is better

Comment: I wouldn't say better, just bit compacter. As for dynamic properties, you should check out the function [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/functions/attribute.html)